# How to resolve Error response from docker daemon - executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

After `successfully build` docker Image using command `docker build . -t HellowWorld-netcore`

I got bellow Error at the time of run docker using command `docker run -d -p 8082:8082  HelloWorld-netcore`

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec:
> "dotnet": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

***Dockerfile content***

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:3.1
COPY src .
EXPOSE 8082
CMD ["dotnet", "./HelloWorld.dll"]
```

Under `src` file all the supportive `dll`, `HellowWorld.dll` & `HellowWorld.exe` file exists. `src` folder & `Dockerfile` is in the same root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

made some changes in **Dockerfile** and the program run as expected

***Code Snippet***

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 
RUN mkdir app

COPY ./src/* /app/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8082
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HelloWorld.dll"]
```

**Note:** It seems to me problem is in .Net Framework. Downloading correct SDK, program running perfectly. And able to get the output from `browser` as well using (`http://localhost:8082/HellowWorld`).